# What is the proper way to validate and sanitize JSON response from REST API?

Tags: database, rest-api, validation, sanitization

I have read the [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/) page about this but didn't find a solution.

Here are my details:

register rest route:

```
register_rest_route(
    '/jwt-auth/v1',
    '/user',
    array(
        'methods'             => array( 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT' ),
        'callback'            => array( $this, 'user_get_information' ),
        'permission_callback' => function() {
            return is_user_logged_in();
        },
    ),
);
```

user function :

```
public function user_get_information( $request ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $data    = array();
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD' ) === 'POST' ) {
        $params = array(
            'nickname',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'mobile',
            'favorites',
            'playtime',
        );

        $allreq = $request->get_params();

        foreach ( $allreq as $req => $val ) {
            if ( ! empty( $val ) && in_array( $req, $params, true ) ) {
                if ( 'favorites' === $req ) {
                    // do somthing
                } elseif ( 'playtime' === $req ) { 

// i want this json data validate and sanitize then add to database

                    $meta      = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'playtime', true );
                    $schema    = $this->user_playtime_meta_schema();
                    if ( rest_validate_value_from_schema( $val, $schema ) ) {
                        $sanitized = rest_sanitize_value_from_schema( $val, $schema );
                    }
                    if ( ! is_array( $meta ) ) {
                        $meta = array();
                    }
                    $meta[] = $sanitized;
                    // $meta = array();
                } else {
                    $meta = $val;
                }
                $user_meta = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'playtime', $meta );
            }
        }
    }
    if ( is_wp_error( $user_meta ) ) {
        $error_string = $user_meta->get_error_message();
        return $error_string;
    } else {
        $info   = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
        $meta   = get_user_meta( $user_id );
        $img_id = $meta['image_select'][0];
        if ( $img_id ) {
            $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id );
        }
        $data['id']           = $info->ID;
        $data['login']        = $info->user_login;
        $data['email']        = $info->user_email;
        $data['display_name'] = $info->display_name;
        $data['image']        = $img_url;
        $data['nickname']     = $meta['nickname'][0];
        $data['first_name']   = $meta['first_name'][0];
        $data['last_name']    = $meta['last_name'][0];
        $data['mobile']       = $meta['mobile'][0];
        $data['favorites']    = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorites', true );
        $data['playtime']     = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'playtime', true );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

schema :

```
public function user_playtime_meta_schema() {
    if ( $this->playtime_schema ) {
        return $this->playtime_schema;
    }
    $this->playtime_schema = array(
        'type' => array(
            'type'       => 'object',
            'properties' => array(
                'song'     => array(
                    'type'       => 'object',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'name'  => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ),
                        'id'    => array(
                            'type' => 'number',
                        ),
                        'notes' => array(
                            'type' => 'number',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'time'     => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'date'     => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'score'    => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
                'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $this->playtime_schema;
}
```

try send data like this:

```
{"playtime":{"song": {
        "name": "Training New",
        "id": 758,
        "notes": 65
    },
    "time": "10:27:19 PM",
    "score": "[[76,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[77,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[74,\"late\"],[72,\"late\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[77,\"perfect\"],[76,\"late\"],[74,\"late\"],[72,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[76,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[72,\"perfect\"],[71,\"perfect\"],[67,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[72,\"perfect\"],[74,\"perfect\"],[71,\"perfect\"],[72,\"perfect\"],[74,\"late\"],[71,\"perfect\"],[72,\"perfect\"],[71,\"late\"],[67,\"perfect\"]]",
    "date": "8/17/2020",
    "progress": "4%"}
}
```

everything works , but if i send some bad information like this :

```
    {"playtime":{"wrong": {
        "number": "1",
        "notes": 525
    },
    "time": "10:27:19 PM",
    "progress": "4%"}
}
```

also works and wrong data would be saved in database!

Comment: You're already calling `rest_validate_value_from_schema` - doesn't that do what you want? You need to check the return value for is_wp_error() though.

Comment: this function `rest_validate_value_from_schema` always return true somehow, i think somewhere should missing.

Comment: i have tested `if ( ! is_wp_error( rest_validate_value_from_schema( $val, $schema ) ) )` and didnt get error just now! , and still wrong data saved in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @GTsvetanov from Stackoverflow.com.

Missing part of my code is `$request->get_json_params();` for getting json request then compare it with schema using `rest_validate_value_from_schema()` then using `rest_sanitize_value_from_schema()` for saving proper data to database.

```
    $schema = $this->user_playtime_meta_schema();
    $val    = $request->get_json_params();//<-- my mistake
    $result = rest_validate_value_from_schema( $values, $schema );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( rest_validate_value_from_schema( $val, $schema ) ) ) {
        $sanitized = rest_sanitize_value_from_schema( $val, $schema );
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
    $user_meta = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'playtime', $sanitized );
```